# PFObject isDirty cleared on call or on callback?

Tags: parse-platform, pfobject

When is `PFObject`'s `isDirty` property set to `NO` - is it at the moment I call `[PFObject save...]` method, or when that method receives a successful callback, i.e. a confirmation from the server that the save has been successful?

Comment: A quick Note, I pin to local data store and then use saveEventually to to ensure saving when online. I was surprised to see that after saving to the cloud isDirt is still true. Very unexpected, as the data was replicated to the cloud....